# How to setup TF 2.4 Training data with generator or other means

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tensorflow2.x

I have a model setup with one input and two outputs. I am trying to use any of

1. [tf.data.Dataset.from_generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_python_generators)
2. [fit with regular python
   generator](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#other_input_formats_supported)
3. [tf.data.TFRecordDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset)

So far all my attempts have run into errors, which I can only assume is based on the shape/types involved in my output from the generators I've tried setting up. What format should the output of such a generator be?
I am also super open to suggestions for doing this differently
You can [download my whole notebook here](https://jdc-public-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/text_extraction.ipynb) if you'd like to look through

### The Input

The input to the model is of shape

```
(None,)
```

And is of type

```
tf.string
```

I am able to get model output with

```
model(tf.constant(['Hello TensorFlow!']))
```

### The outputs

There are two output heads for the model, the first is of shape

```
(None, 128, 5)
```

The second is of shape

```
(None, 128, 3)
```

They both are of type

```
tf.float32
```

The loss for my model is sparse categorical crossentropy. (I want a softmax across 5 or 3 classes depending on the head, for each of the 128 outputs, with the None being there for the batch size). I believed for this the proper output format would be a tuple of batch_size instances of the following format

```
(input_string, (output_for_head1, output_for_head2))
```

where input_string is a string, output_for_head1 and output_for_head2 are both numpy arrays of shape (128) and type int.

### Some random things I've tried for fitting on generator directly

#### Yield single item rather than whole batch (using batch size 10 for all testing)

Gets index out of bounds error- pretty sure this needs to be batched

#### Yield whole batch

Get error

```
    Data is expected to be in format `x`, `(x,)`, `(x, y)`, or `(x, y, sample_weight)`, found: ((<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'Ya Yeet'>, (<tf.Tensor: shape=(128,), dtype=int64, numpy=... ( a very long set of (128,) tensors which is too large to post here)


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_95064]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to this using generators. I was able to first create a generator yielding numpy arrays that the model could be trained on directly, and then create a tf.data dataset from a slightly modified version of that generator.

The solution was to output just 3 numpy arrays per batch like
`input_arr, (output_arr1, output_arr2)` the shape of each array was expanded to have the batch size on the left, rather than having a tuple of length batch_size.

The final generators looked like this

```
def text_data_generator(dataset_path, batch_size, input_text_col='text', output_classes_col='labels', classes=CLASSES, continuity_classes=CONTINUITY_CLASSES, pad_length=128, sep=' '):
    while True:
        for chunk in pd.read_csv(dataset_path, chunksize=batch_size):
            #TODO : Should probably shuffle the dataset somehow
            texts = chunk['text'].values
            c_classes = np.stack(chunk['classes'].apply(lambda x : pad([classes.index(item) for item in x.split(sep)])).values)
            c_continuity = np.stack(chunk['continuity'].apply(lambda x : pad([continuity_classes.index(item) for item in x.split(sep)])).values)
            texts = np.array(texts)
            c_classes = np.array(c_classes)
            c_continuity = np.array(c_continuity)
            yield texts, (c_classes, c_continuity)
```

and

```
def tf_text_data_generator(dataset_path, batch_size, input_text_col='text', output_classes_col='labels', classes=CLASSES, continuity_classes=CONTINUITY_CLASSES, pad_length=128, sep=' '):
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(dataset_path, chunksize=batch_size):
        texts = chunk['text'].values
        c_classes = np.stack(chunk['classes'].apply(lambda x : pad([classes.index(item) for item in x.split(sep)])).values)
        c_continuity = np.stack(chunk['continuity'].apply(lambda x : pad([continuity_classes.index(item) for item in x.split(sep)])).values)
        texts = np.array(texts)
        c_classes = np.array(c_classes)
        c_continuity = np.array(c_continuity)
        yield texts, (c_classes, c_continuity)
```

The model could be trained directly on an instance of text_data_generator. To train on the other generator I created a tf.data.Dataset by

```
def wrapped_gen():
    return tf_text_data_generator("test.csv", 10)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(wrapped_gen, (tf.string, (tf.int64, tf.int64)))
```

which then can be passed directly to model.train just as the instantiated generator could be.